# Redirecting to another page - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to redirect the user to a page named test.php when he types the url of my site (example www.domain.com).
Pratically by typing www.domain.com the browser should show www.domain.com/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At index.html or index.php, you could add meta refresh tag like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;www.domain.com/test.php" />
```

If you use index.php, the syntax would be like this:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;www.domain.com/test.php" />';
```

Add **http://** at the url if You want to redirect to another domain.

Comment: So I shouldn't add anything in the htaccess file? Just leave it?

Comment: Yes.. leave it, or there are another way to reach your mind via htaccess, but it is not a must

Answer (score 0):

In top of your .htaccess file try this rules (except files and directories rewrite anything www/non www to example.com/test.php)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/test.php [L]
</IfModule>
```